# Use of DefaultTextStyle in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to apply a `DefaultTextStyle`, but even though the style is defined and available (as established by calling `DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style`), it does not get applied by default to child `Text` objects.  So what am I doing wrong, or failing to understand?

Here is the `build` method from my calling class, where I define my `DefaultTextStyle`:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) =>
      Strings.of(context).getStr('app_title'),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const StringsDelegate(),
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback: Strings.resolveLocale,
      // Watch out: MaterialApp creates a Localizations widget
      // with the specified delegates. DemoLocalizations.of()
      // will only find the app's Localizations widget if its
      // context is a child of the app.
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
      home: new DefaultTextStyle(
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
          decorationColor: Colors.red,
          decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy,
          color: Colors.blue
          ),
        child: new StatusPage())
      );
  }
```

And here is `StatusPage`, where I am trying to use the `DefaultTextStyle`:

```
class StatusPage extends MyStatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle style = DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style;
    print("STYLE: $style");
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: getText(context, 'app_title')
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('wibble', style:style),
            new ActivityStatus(),
            new MonitoringStatus()]
          )));
  }
}
```

With the code as shown, the Text "wibble" is correctly shown with the appropriate style.  My understanding from the docs, is that this style should be applied by default, so I should not need the style argument to the `Text` constructor for "wibble".

However, if I remove the style argument I do not get the style from my `DefaultTextStyle`.

What am I missing?

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/beginners-guide-to-text-styling-in-flutter-3939085d6607) suggests making changes via the theme.

Comment: DefaultTextStyle is for `Text`s with no `style` prop, but you set it!

Answer (score 13):

Apply the [DefaultTextStyle](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html) to the [Scaffold](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) like this and you will get this style in all the descendant Text widgets

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new StatusPage());
  }
}

class StatusPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle style = DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style;
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(),
        body: new DefaultTextStyle(
            style: new TextStyle(
                inherit: true,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                decorationColor: Colors.red,
                decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy,
                color: Colors.blue),
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text("hello"),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks that works.  But the default does not remain in play for children of the children.  As far as I can tell, various widgets put their own `DefaultTextStyle`s into the context tree, making the value of a default somewhat limited.  Can you provide any further clarification about how this is supposed to work?  The docs in this area don't give us much.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue before, I think it comes when using custome fonts or changing language (at least that was my case)
the solution for me was to go `MaterialApp`  widget and then override ALL `textTheme` attributes like this:

```
fontFamily: "STCBold",
              textTheme: GoogleFonts.cairoTextTheme(textTheme).copyWith(
                  headline1: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  headline2: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  headline3: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  headline4: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  headline5: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  headline6: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  subtitle1: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  subtitle2: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  bodyText1: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  bodyText2: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  caption: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  button: TextStyle(height: 1),
                  overline: TextStyle(height: 1),
              ),
```

this will make all text themes have no extra padding thus all texts will be tight. but make sure to use `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.WHATEVERTEXT.` in all your code

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I was trying to change the text color of the `Text` widgets in a `Card`.
I had this code, but didn't work:

```
DefaultTextStyle.merge(
 style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
 child: Card(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Text("Should be red"),
 ),
)
```

That doesn't work because the `Card` widget creates a `Material` widget and the `Text` widget inside the `Card` uses the `TextStyle` from the Material widget. This is why wrapping the `Card` with `DefaultTextStyle.merge` does not change the text color.

To change the text color inside a `Card`, you can wrap the Text widget with `DefaultTextStyle.merge`:

```
Card(
 color: Colors.blue,
 child: DefaultTextStyle.merge(
 style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
 child: const Text("Should be red"),
 ),
)
```