# How do i override scaffold backGround or default text size locally in flutter?

Tags: flutter

using the technique described in https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes#creating-unique-themedata I can modify `accentColor`, `splashColor` but not `scaffoldColor` or text size

https://github.com/neiljaywarner/local_theme_test

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const smallDefault = const TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0));
const bigDefault = const TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 54.0));
var orangeBrown = ThemeData(
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.brown, 
  textTheme: smallDefault, 
  accentColor: Colors.orange,
);
var bluePink = ThemeData(
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue, 
  textTheme: bigDefault, 
  accentColor: Colors.pink,
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Primary Text theme override',
      theme: orangeBrown,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Theme(
            data: bluePink,
            child: Text('?why small??'),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Theme(
          data: bluePink,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding why the Text widget font size does not change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806705/use-of-defaulttextstyle-in-flutter. You do not apply any style to your Text Widget.